# VBA - How to add sheets to an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

I have little experience with loops/arrays in VBA.  I am looking to copy all tabs that start with "FY" in the name to a new wb.  Where I am having difficulty is adding the tabs to the array to copy based on criteria as I do not know nor have been able to find the syntax for this.
I added in the MsgBox line as a placeholder.

```
Sub Generate_Report()
Dim current As Worksheet
Dim currentname As String

'----Add tab name to array if starts with 'FY'----
For Each current In Worksheets
    currentname = current.Name
    If Left(currentname, 2) = "FY" Then
    MsgBox ("Add this tab to the array")
Next

End Sub`
```

Comment: What do you plan to do with this array? IOW, an array may not be the best choice here.

Comment: @BigBen I want to take the array of sheets to copy to a new wb.  Each month will be given its own sheet.  The goal is to generate an excel report with static values off of the source file.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just copy the sheet within your existing loop? Why do you need an array?

Comment: @BigBen My thought was that the month's tab would not be created until the month's data became available. So, I thought adding the tabs to an array as they became available could be copied over. Open to other suggestions that was just my original thought.

Comment: I don't think you need an array here at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use an array you *could* do something like this

```
Dim demo1(10) As Worksheet
Dim apointer As Integer
apointer = 0

Dim current As Worksheet, currentname As String
For Each current In Worksheets
    currentname = current.Name
    If Left(currentname, 2) = "FY" Then
        Set demo1(apointer) = current
        apointer = apointer + 1
    End If
Next
```

The main problem here is the maximum number of sheets you can store is 11 (the array runs from cell 0 to cell 10 by default).

You might be tempted to use a "dynamic" array E.G.

```
Dim demo1() As WorkSheet

Dim apointer As Integer
apointer = 0

Dim current As Worksheet, currentname As String
For Each current In Worksheets
    currentname = current.Name
    If Left(currentname, 2) = "FY" Then
        ReDim Preserve demo1(apointer)
        demo1(apointer) = current
        apointer = apointer + 1
    End If
Next
```

But it would probably be far better to use a Collection (or a Dictionary), or even a ListBox See [Collection Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/collection-object)

Comment: Instead of `Redim Preserve` each time, it makes more sense to set the array size to `Worksheets.Count` at the start, and then `Redim Preserve` a single time at the end, once you have the accurate number.

Comment: @BigBen - D'oh, my bad. I will fix that.

Comment: @Toddleson - true - I'll leave it as is - if you want to post the improvement it gets my vote

Comment: IIRC, `demo1(apointer) = current` is missing a `Set`.